# How to encrypt webapp in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption

I have the following problem:

1) I have a server on tomcat with database

2) I have a thick client on client machines, which uses it's own tomcat and communicates with server via database synchronization

3) In my webapp there are config files with passwords to both databases

4) I need to have the ability to turn off client from server, without dataloss but preventing client from accessing data (i.e. clients are free-lancers for company and they shoud have access to data only while working for them)

They only interact with data from inside the app, which is login restricted with login hash being in database. So when we want to "disconnect" a user we change his password, and after synchronization he's left out.

Yet, he still can go to the webapps folder, find configs and thus connect to database (not only client, but also server). So what I need is a way to deploy somehow encrypted `war`s to Tomcat.

Also I'd like to make Tomcat extract this `war` into somehow encrypted directory, for I sometimes make interface updates, and since clients have awful internet connections (hence this overly-complicated deployment structure), it's important to update *only* files that need updating.

But the last question is less important, since I can set tomcat to not unpack `war`s and make clients suffer huge downloads for updates (workable, yet undesireable solution)

Comment: and tomcat would still be able to use all the webapps? it should also be able to decrypt them

Comment: @brso05 You misunderstood, I store login/password to the DATABASE on the server, because I need to use it from time to time to sync. As it's in plain text, user will have access to the db after he shouldn't

Comment: is the password used directly by the user or the web app (program)?

Comment: by webapp (it's hibernate config file)

Comment: as I said in the question, they have bad internet and thus they need to "emulate" server, yet sometimes they have to query actual database

Comment: Umm... you give direct-access to your primary database to remote clients? Sounds like you need to stop doing that, and then it doesn't matter what your primary database's credentials are, since your remote users can't get to it, anyway.

Comment: What you need is not a non-existent way to reply encrypted web apps, it is to fix your poor security practices.